# How to get this limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I guess this limit equals zero.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^2 = 0.$$

Am I right?

If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $\sum_na_n$ is a convergent series with sum $s$, then $$\sum_{k>n}a_n=s-S_n$$ where $S_n$ is the partial sum $\sum^n_{k=0}a_n$ and by definition $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}S_n=s$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{2},\quad S=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{2}.$$

Notice that $S$ is finite (do you see why?). The limit you wish to find is $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(S-S_n)$. Clearly, $S_n$ tends towards $S$, so that $S-S_n$ tends towards $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$S_n= \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(n+1)$$ Using the asymptotics
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{1}{6
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

For illustration, computing exactly
$$S_{1000}=0.000999500166666633\cdots$$while the truncated series would give
$$S_{1000}=\frac{5997001}{6000000000}=0.000999500166666667\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
0<\sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(k + 1)^2 }}}  < \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{\mathrm{d}x}}{{x^2 }}} }  = \int_n^\infty  {\frac{{\mathrm{d}x}}{{x^2 }}}  = \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Now apply the squeeze theorem. Alternatively,
$$
0<\sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(k + 1)^2 }}}  \le \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{k(k + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{{k + 1}}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{n}.
$$